# Pass parameters in visual studio 2017 like nunit-console params cli

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, visual-studio-2017, nunit-3.0

If i run my unit tests using NUnit's nunit3-console CLI utility I'm able to pass parameters using the "params" flag like so:

```
>nunit3-console --params:testKey=test203 TestClass.dll
```

Debugging in VS is really annoying because I have to set the flag "--debug", i then have to attach to the process from visual studio. My question is whether it's possible to somehow pass in that same parameter to my unit tests using only visual studio?

The reason I need to pass in params this way is because I need it in my setup methods and Nunit does not allow me to dynamically change it using a variable.

Comment: We currently don't support that in the Visual Studio adapter. Unfortunately we are limited by the UI that Visual Studio provides. Could you switch your Setup methods to look for the parameters first, then if they don't exist look for environment variables? You could set the environment variables before you launch VS.

Comment: You could also read in a configuration files for your tests if you don't want to mess with env variables.

Comment: @RobProuse Thank you for that, any plans to support this in VS at some point? Assuming VS allows. I will try both environment variables and configuration files to see if either of those work, for the purposes of my testing config files might be my best option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You specify the run parameters in your `.runsettings` file. Here's what an example file with no other settings would look like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>

  <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="webAppUrl" value="http://localhost" />
    <Parameter name="webAppUserName" value="Admin" />
    <Parameter name="webAppPassword" value="Password" />
  </TestRunParameters>

</RunSettings>
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize you added parameters to run settings too. I thought it was still just command line